# How to serve a gziped font using .htaccess? (no mod gzip or deflate)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, webfonts

Here's a list of stuff I tried in random order:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .otf
AddType
default_mimetype
auto_prepend_file = "otf.php"
zlib.output_compression = On
output_handler = ob_gzhandler
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
```

Even though all the PHP files of the server get gzipped using zlib, replacing the .otf extension by .php didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With .htaccess, you could do like this, assuming font file is `fontfile.otf.gz`, browser request that as `fontfile.otf`

```
RewriteEngine On

#Check for browser's Accept-Encoding, remove it for force return gzipped one
RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept-Encoding}" "gzip.*deflate|deflate.*gzip"

#check file name is endswith otf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "\.(otf)$"

#check existance of .gz file name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s

#rewrite it to .otf.gz
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}.gz [L]

#update some response header
<FilesMatch "\.otf\.gz$">
    AddEncoding gzip .gz
    ForceType "text/plain"
</FilesMatch>
```

And if font file and web site is cross-domain, you need to put `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, firefox will not load [font objects cross-domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=En/CSS/%40font-face).

> In Gecko, web fonts are subject to the
>   same domain restriction (font files
>   must be on the same domain as the page
>   using them), unless HTTP access
>   controls are used to relax this
>   restriction.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

Comment: thx for answering // i copy pasted and tried it // it's not working (the font isn't getting gzipped) checking using firebug on firefox 3.5 // the forcetype isn't working either (application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template instead) // do i have to replace REQUEST_FILENAME or REQUEST_URI?

Comment: you have gzipped file made in advance, right? you can try removing accept-encoding check line by commenting out.

Comment: you can check out this page with firebug here - http://test.my-mm.org/font/embed.htm. its working and I am using similar way in my blog.

Comment: and if you are loading font cross-domain, you need to put Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in header, updated my post too.

Comment: ok iv pre-gziped my font and it's working - THANK YOU! // 
but you didn't really answer the question (i wanted the server to gzip on the fly) // 
so if you don't mind ill let other users answer before accepting your solution // off topic - do you know a good gzipper(max compression)?

Comment: as far as i know, on the fly gzipping is done by mod gzip or mod deflate, you mentioned (no mod gzip or deflate) in title, may be thats why other people are not answering.

Comment: yes but there are still ob_gzhandler and zlib.output_compression (which are not modules you need to install)

Comment: I see, if you want specific answer for those method, you can raise new question and ask for "how to enable compression for font object using ob_gzhandler and zlib.output_compression",

Comment: you are right my question must have been badly formulated // btw the proper ForceType is "font/opentype"